# Send an http request in mysql trigger after insertion in a table

Tags: php, mysql, http, triggers

I am working in PHP.I have to created a mysql trigger which fires an http request after insertion on table.Below is the code.

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trigger
AFTER INSERT ON insertsms
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @tt_json = (SELECT json_object(id,addtime,title) 
                  FROM insertsms WHERE id = NEW.id LIMIT 1);
  SET @tt_resu = (SELECT http_put(CONCAT('--url localhost--')));
END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```

But I am getting errors like

> Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION emg.json_object does not exist
>
> Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION emg.http_put does not exist

How to remove this error? I was not able to download the supporting files containing these functions.I have tested in localhost.Is there any other way to achieve my requirement? Please anyone help me..

Comment: It looks like these functions are contained in a [library called mysql-udf-http](https://code.google.com/p/mysql-udf-http/) - have you installed it on your database?

Comment: @StuartLC :no.i am first using this trigger.How we can install that file in database?Please help.

Comment: Well, I guess you need to follow the instructions on the page I linked, assuming you are installed on Linux and have control over the server. Just IMO it isn't a great idea to do web requests from a database.

Comment: unfortunately i am working with Windows and how can i download the file and where to add it?Sorry can you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

Although it's technically possible I'd strongly discourage you from going this route for several reasons:

1. Using UDFs is a security risk on its own. UDFs are available to all database users - you cannot grant EXECUTE privileges for them.
2. Doing any **non-transactional** operations in a trigger is **simply wrong**. Data changes made by DML statement (in your case it's an update) can and will be rolled back in a real world scenario. You won't be able to undo your http calls.
3. You're prolonging the time for insert transaction possibly causing lock-wait-timeouts for other update/insert operations.

Highly recommended reading:

- [The Trouble with Triggers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)

---

Now most likely what you need is a work queue e.g. [beanstalked](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd). Using such specialized middleware is much better than organizing queues with database.

Comment: Even if it is risk using trigger,i would like to know how we can create UDF for running this trigger and send an http request...can you please help?

Comment: Judging by the documentation for the library it most likely can't work on Windows. But you can always use a Vagrant virtual machine to put your MySQL instance on one of the linux distributions and be able to install this set of udfs.

Comment: How can i see or download lib_mysqludf_sys?And where to install?Please help