# Can a Lambda function be automatically called when a MySQL (RDS) table has a row created/updated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-lambda

DynamoDB has a feature called "Streams", which can automatically call a Lambda function whenever a table row is created or updated.

Is there a way to implement this with RDS (MySQL) and Lambda?
I would love it if a Lambda function could be called when a row is created or updated.

I know it's possible to poll the database for table/row changes, but I'd rather have the Lambda be triggered from an external event. I also read about RDS Events and using SNS to subscribe to these events. But these RDS Events seem like operational events (Availability, Configuration, Recovery). There are no "events" for data changes.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing there is no easy way to do this. RDS doesn't track actual SQL actions and MySQL doesn't know how to interface with Lambda.

That said, if you take a look at this relevant SO thread ([Send an http request in mysql trigger after insertion in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665066/send-an-http-request-in-mysql-trigger-after-insertion-in-a-table)) it explains how to perform and HTTP request.

Now, if you have a lambda function behind API Gateway and perform an HTTP request, you might be able to accomplish what you want, but [without knowing the application], I would ask whether it would be easier to update your application to trigger the lambda functions itself.

Comment: One problem here is that the http library for MySQL is built as user-defined function (UDF, not the same as a stored function) and UDFs are not supported in RDS.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda can be called from a stored procedure in Aurora. While this is not strictly an RDS MySql option, it is an option where you can move to the MySQL compatible Aurora offering from AWS and accomplish what you were wanting. The question is, how badly do you need this capability and how well does Aurora fit in your budget and architecture. For more information see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Lambda.html