# How to call a URL in the mysql trigger after inserting a record in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a PHP file which runs a Web service sending as data, the records of my table for the insertion of them in a table of another system. I want to execute the URL that calls the file, only when a new record is inserted in my table and I'm not executing every time the call to the url to do all this process.

I have seen what can be done with this procedure:

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trigger
AFTER INSERT ON insertsms
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET @tt_resu = (SELECT http_put(CONCAT('--url localhost--')));
END;
@@
DELIMITER ;
```

But I get this error `Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION emg.http_put does not exist.`

Any idea how to do it ?, or how else can it be done?

Comment: As the error message says, you need to create the http_put function. Google it & you will find example CREATE FUNCTION statements. Example URL is here though I have /not/ tried it: http://open-bi.blogspot.com/2012/11/call-restful-web-services-from-mysql.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665066/send-an-http-request-in-mysql-trigger-after-insertion-in-a-table?lq=1